# Possible way to use the .setVisible method in java as a counter?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am practising my GUI skills is java, and my program is basically to have a simple quiz on yes or no questions. What I am trying to do here is that when the user clicks on the button yes, the "correct" JLabel appears on the top of the screen using the .setVisible method. However, one of the requirements of the program is to keep a score and therefore, I was wondering if I could have an if statement or something that will increase the value of the counter every time the "correct" JLabel is visible.

Here is the action listener for the button:

```
 yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pressed)
            {
                questions.setText(".......");
                correct.setVisible(true);
                if(correct.setVisible(true))//causes error
                {
                    counter+=1;
                }

            }
});
```

I would appreciate any help, however, I would also appreciate that you don't do it for me, thanks!

Also if any other parts of the code are required, please feel free to ask!

Comment: Can you post the specific error message please.

Comment: Why the if statement? you have just setVisible to true so no need to check for it. Just increment the counter right away. It will probably get more complex once you are evaluating if the answer is actually correct, but it seems you are not there yet.

Comment: "void cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: Would that work @Voooza ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `setVisible(boolean)` is a void method (see [Component.setVisible(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible-boolean-).

As a result, it cannot be used in an `if` statement.

It may be possible to use `.isVisible()`, to determine if it has been set.

For example, I think the code could be modified to:

```
correct.setVisible(true);
if (correct.isVisible()) {
  ++counter;
}
```

Here is [the javadoc for .isVisible()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible--)

Comment: yep in other words

Comment: Oh ok, fair enough, what is .isVisible(), i'm not familiar with it?

Comment: @Tea_Cups, technically, `.isVisible()` returns whether the component is visible to the parent. However, after `.setVisible(true);`, I presume the `.isVisible()` will return true. Nonetheless, unless you are checking this object from elsewhere, since the component was just set to visible, I would think it would be possible to just increment the counter.

Comment: @Tea_Cups not familiar ? maybe google it, read the doc (given in the post^^) Search ! if you don't you don't deserve to code

Comment: Oh I see, i'll give it a go @KevinO

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with the code given above, and tried to output the code as a JTextField, however, there are a few issues with outputting the score, I can fix that simply, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
correct.setVisible(true);
```

That expression does not return value (void) thus cannot be used as `boolean`. `boolean` is required for `if` statements